# Camunda Identity Service for an embedded installation

Tags: camunda

I’m using Camunda embedded in my web application (springboot). I successfully created my custom identityProvider (implementing ReadOnlyIdentityProvider) and my users and groups are being read from my database.

The thing is, I thought Camunda would check, for example, that certain user can only claim a task if he/she belongs to the candidate group, but I don’t see that happening. For example, I logged to cockpit with a user with group A, and was able to claim a task assigned to candidate group B.

So my question is, why would I need to create an IdentityProvider? Camunda webapps will be accessed by admins only, so I don’t need to setup resource security there. Is there a use case or something that I’m missing?

PD: Also asked in https://forum.camunda.org/t/do-i-need-an-identity-service-for-an-embedded-installation/10378

Answer (score 0):

Claiming a task is not forbidden by camunda if you are not member of the candidate group of the task.
So I guess setting the tasklist filters in a way where a user that is not member of a group is not able to see the task will be your solution.

Comment: I agree on what you say, but my question is why would I need a custom IdentityProvider? I mean, if I have to do the checks by hand, I don't see why I would need one. The only reason I can think of is if I want to use my user base to give resource permissions to camunda apps